# programatic addition of template fields based on database columns gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have the following scenario where a patient has a list of diseases and I have to show the patient name and the list of diseases as columns in a gridview.

I have the datatable that has patientID, patientName and all the diseases as columns (representing 1 or 0 values based on the disease exists for a member)

If I bind the datatable directly, I will get patient and all diseases with 1 and 0 values
However, I want this gridview to have patientName as one column and all the diseases as other columns and in future if a disease is added, I want a column to be added to GridView as well

The Gridview has patient name under patient Column
and checkbox in everycolumn under a disease (if the disease exists for that member, the checkbox is checked by default during binding)

And as an user, I should be able to check/uncheck those if a new disease affects the patient and update the information to the database.

If, it is a bound field, I am able to do this but inorder to support the case of checkbox and editing, I have to go for a template field and item template, but I am not sure how to do it.

Can you please help me with the code to do that.

[Data Table looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbe6P.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide sample code or a sample dataset to assist in providing a better answer to this question.

Comment: Hi @mattdonders, attached the datatable

Comment: The easiest way would be to add/remove columns from the DataTable before binding to a GridView with AutoGenerated columns. Or create a lot of  extra TemplateFields than are hidden or shown in the RowDataBound event.